# How to keep track of appsync validation errors on cloudwatch?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-cloudwatch, aws-appsync

I have custom resolvers on appsync that are handled by lambda functions, I can keep track of errors logs created by the lambda functions by using cloudwatch and creating alarms based on these logs. But when client applications tries to request fields that don't exist on the graphql schema(see image below) the lambda runs fine so none error log its created, how can I keep track of these kind of errors using cloudwatch?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The good news is that you can turn on [AppSync request logging](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/appsync/latest/devguide/monitoring.html#log-type-reference) to get request-level logs in CloudWatch.  Configure logging using Cloudformation/CDK [LogConfig](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-appsync-graphqlapi-logconfig.html) or directly in the AppSync console.

The bad news is that the logged events do not seem to call out failed validations.  Both well-formed and malformed requests are logged similarly, it seems.  Log level `INFO` versus `ERROR` does not seem to help.

There may be a way to look for log patterns (malformed requests won't call the resolver) to distinguish good from bad requests, but this does not seem straightforward.  Perhaps you will have better luck than I did!

Example of log entries for one request:

```
Begin Request
GraphQL Query: query Labels { labelStats(topic: "cars") { name objects __typename } } , Operation: Labels,...
{"duration":201275210,"logType":"ExecutionSummary","requestId":"4f49d425-18ab-4be7-a40e-0229c17453dc","startTime":"2021-12-17T16:36:30.925216Z","e...
{"logType":"RequestSummary","requestId":"4f49d425-18ab-4be7-a40e-0229c17453dc","graphQLAPIId":"xxxxxxxxxx","statusCode":200,"lat...
Request Headers: {content-length=[148], cloudfront-viewer-country=[US], x-forwarded-proto=[https], x-amzn-r...
Response Headers: {Content-Type=application/json; charset=UTF-8}
End Request
```